# Recursive function to add values is outputting unusual values

Tags: c, recursion, while-loop, output, tail-recursion

I have a program that uses a tail recursion function to add the value entered and all the previous values. For example if the user enters 3, the function calculates 3+2+1 and gets an answer of 6. However this only sometimes works.

Here is my code below:

```
int addNum(int n);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int num;
  printf("Enter an integer greater than zero, (q to quit): \n");
  while(scanf("%d", &num) > 0){
      if(num < 0){
          continue;  
      }
      else if(num == 0){

          printf("Answer = 0 \n");
      }
      else{

          printf("Answer = %d \n", addNum(num)); 
      }
      printf("Enter a positive number: \n");

  }
  return 0;
}

int addNum(int n){
  int answer;
  if(n > 0){
    answer = n += addNum(n - 1);   
  }
  return answer;
}
```

The output I get from this code is very peculiar. For numbers 0-6 I get the right answers. Once I get to 7 and 8 both the answers are incorrect. I keep going and 9-12 the answers are correct again. Then 13 and 14 are incorrect. It keeps going back and fourth like this. I have absolutely no clue what is going on if someone could help. If it is something simple and wrong with my code please don't give me the answer but rather a hint at the problem.

I will post the output below so you can see what is going on. I decided to use pastebin for my output to save room. http://pastebin.com/DjJfxJAT

Comment: Enable compiler warnings...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize `answer` in `addNum()`, so whenever you call it with n == 0, [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) occurs since you end up returning an uninitialized value. It's only by luck that you ever get the right answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think this code itself explains things

```
int addNum(int n);
int answer=0;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {


  int num;

  printf("Enter an integer greater than zero, (q to quit): \n");


  while(scanf("%d", &num) > 0){


      if(num < 0){
          continue;
      }
      else if(num == 0){

          printf("Answer = 0 \n");
      }
      else{
          answer=0;
          printf("Answer = %d \n", addNum(num));
      }

      printf("Enter a positive number: \n");

      }

  return 0;
}
  int addNum(int n){


      if(n > 0){

        answer = n += addNum(n - 1);
      }
      return answer;
  }
```

Comment: I didn't down vote you someone else did. Can you explain what you mean by pasting my code? I am new to C and just trying to learn. Every mistake I make is a lesson that I can learn from to become a better programmer. If you have an actual suggestion on how I can improve I am all ears and would love that. If you just want to be arrogant then you can do that too.

Comment: Actually in your code for each and every input you give you are not making variable answer =0.  So if first input is 2 the output is 3(answer=3) If second input is 5 your are returning 3+(5+4+3+2+1).....(answer=18) and so on... so i just corrected your code and pasted but didn't copy paste it. I hope you get it..